# How to observe IOS native event notification in Flutter ? Like UIKeyboardWillShowNotification etc

Tags: ios, flutter

I want to observer some IOS native notification in Flutter, Like UIKeyboardWillShowNotification etc.. How to observe IOS native event notification in Flutter?